# Redirect pages using useHistory and remove image when click is false

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-functional-component

[image]

With useEffect I tried to compare the right sequence with the right clicks and if it is true, automatically redirect to another page. If you make a mistake four times you will be redirected to the Loose page, with each error remove an image. How do I redirect the pages and how do I delete the images as the click is false?

```
useEffect(() => {
const correctSequence = [4, 5, 7, 8, 9];
if (correctSequence === sequence) {<Redirect to="/Win" />;
} else {<Redirect to="/Loose" />;}
console.log(sequence);
console.log(correctSequence);}, [sequence]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/puzzle-react-koohr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use useHistory() react hook.
Make a function that checks if the orders are right and use history.

```html
const history = useHistory();

const correctSequence = [4, 5, 7, 8, 9];

const compare = () => {
  if (correctSequence === sequence){
    history.push("/Win");
  } else {
    history.push("/Loose");
  }
}
```

Comment: Too bad it didn't work here, when I try to click on the right words "s, t, a, c, k" it does not redirect to Win. I also tried making mistakes 4 times and it was also not redirected as well as the images did not disappear as I clicked ... Do you know how to solve this? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly redirect from useEffect using `<Redirect />`, you will need:

```
props.history.push('/Win')
```

Same for `/Loose`.

Don't forget to wrap your component with `withRouter`.

Comment: Cool didn’t know that, it could also help me with the right and wrong logic it’s not working either